# Change form title for a custom entity

Tags: 8

I'm just trying to clone a d7 site in 8.  My first step was to use drupal console to generate a custom entity.  Everything is working fine but I want to change the title of the form to "Create project" instead of the default "Add project".

I don't see "Add " anywhere *except* for `module.links.action.yml`, but that is just the local action - it doesn't change the name of the form.

The root of the directory looks like:

```
config
  schema
    project_entity_type.schema.yml
src
  Entity
    ...several classes
  Form
    ...several classes
  templates
    ...couple template files
  Tests
    LoadTest.php
module.page.inc
module.links.action.yml
module.links.menu.yml
module.links.tasks.yml
module.module
module.permissions.yml
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Saulius This was just a play-around project so it never made it past a demo phase; however, I posted my solution below - not sure if it's the best way or not.

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643.

Note: change "module" in the below code to the name of your module.

The first step is to register an event subscriber service. In `module.services.yml`:

```
services:
  module.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Next, create your class `RouteSubscriber` and extend `RouteSubscriberBase`:

```
  namespace Drupal\module\Routing;

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  /**
   * Subscribe to the Route to change page titles.
   */
  class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    private function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('entity.project_entity.add_form')) {
        // set the title (or override '_title_callback' below)
        $route->setDefault('_title', 'Create Project Request');
        // unset the _title_callback; alternatively you could override it here
        $route->setDefault('_title_callback', '');
      }
    }
  }
```

Note that you receive a `RouteCollection` in `alterRoutes` and then using the `$collection-get()` will return an instance of `Route`.  The documentation for Route can be found here: http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.html

If you're having trouble figuring out what your routes are, the excellent drupal console `drupal route:debug` tool will help you.

Comment: To bad this doesn't seems to work on the html `<title>`, works great for the page title 'tho. :)