# How to hide node/add and */edit page titles

Tags: theming

Need to change Drupal 8 node/add page titles - there have been some answers here (most for Drupal 7), but none of them have worked.

So there is always Create  in front of the title in add page - need to drop the part Create - how ?

Need to drop also word Edit  in from the already created node in edit mode - how ?

If someone can point me in right direction and give me _preprocess_node_add_list or some node preprocess sample.

Regards

Virgo

Comment: Their is a similar question existing, that can be useful for you : [Change form title for a custom entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218613/change-form-title-for-a-custom-entity).

Answer (score 1):

Try with `hook_preprocess_page_title`

```
function myModule_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  //- Get the Current route name 
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  switch ($route_name) {
    //- Add node Page
    case 'node.add' :
      $variables['title'] = t('New add page title');
      break;
    //- Edit node Page
    case 'entity.node.edit_form' :
      $variables['title'] = t('test');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u all, got my result - although its much easier than I expected (and learn some in between too) . I did it through D8 blocksystem without any programming. This was good for what I was aiming for.